# Only execute SELECT statement IF something

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm trying to print all the comments from my database, but only if they have been approved.

I recently heard that you can use if statements in your SQL, but I'm not exactly sure how it works.

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT name, created, comment IF('approved' = 1) FROM table_example WHERE id = 3
```

It should only execute the statement `IF 'approved' = 1`.

Can I do something like this or is it way off?

Comment: that is so totally not what IF() statements are for. they can't include/exclude records from your result set. that's why there's a `where` clause. all they can do is modify the value of a particular FIELD in your result set.

Comment: First of all is there a Column in a table in your database where you can check which comments are approved? Or it's a paramater from outside SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name, created, comment FROM table_example WHERE id = 3 AND approved = 1
```

Or am I missing something ??

Comment: That's what I would've thought!

Comment: I can't believe I didn't think of that! Works perfectly.

Comment: @PinkySmartass Sometimes the most obvious can be the hardest to see! :)

Answer (score 2):

you could do something like this:

```
SELECT name, created, 
    CASE
        WHEN approved = 1 THEN comment 
        ELSE NULL 
    END as comment
FROM table_example 
WHERE id = 3
```

you could replace NULL for the default value you want showed if the comment is not approved.

Comment: this will still execute the select when `approved = 1` `comment` will just be `null`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the `DECODE` and `CASE` operators as they are the SQL equivalent of an `IF/ELSE` statement.